# Mini batch K means: how is it guaranteed that at the end every element is labeled?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means

I'm trying to completely understand `Mini Batch K means`

After reading the following pseudo code ...

[image]

We all know that in every iteration, you choose a fixed size batch with a random set of elements from the original data set, in order to calculate the centroids. By doing this, you come to a solution in less time than with the original K means.

Now, it seemed to me that if the iterations are few, and considering the random selection of elements, at the end, when all the final centroids are obtained, some elements may not have been labeled ... so, **at the end, do you need to go over all the (unvisited maybe) elements in the dataset to assign the closest centroid?** I found [this implementation](https://github.com/siddharth-agrawal/Mini-Batch-K-Means) of the algorithm in C, and the author does not do that ...

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minibatch does *not* guarantee to have assigned every object to is closest center. It's designed to be used to find the centers *approximately*, not to label all points.

Now that it does not even guarantee to have visited each point: of you choose a small batch size, and few iterations, many points will be used.

And that is okay: It's trading speed for accuracy, and k-means does not benefit much from "big data", a subsample often is as good for many applications.